# How to set up port forwarding to guest VM using iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, libvirt

I am trying to do a proof of concept for port forwarding to a libvirt guest server.

The following are the variables I use for generalization:

```
port=500                    # Arbitrary port, for proof of concept
public_if=wlp0s20f3         # My public interface, connected to the internet.
private_if=virbr0           # My private interface, through which the guest OS communicates
public_ip=192.168.0.11      # public interface's IP
private_ip=192.168.122.1    # private interface's IP
guest_ip=192.168.122.175    # Guest's IP
```

The guest is just an Ubuntu live CD with the command `sudo nc -l 500 -k` running in a terminal. I test my set up by running `nmap $public_ip -p $port`. When I run `nmap $guest_ip -p $port`, it shows the port as "open".

Of course, this seems like a relatively simple and well documented task, however, none of the tutorials I have tried seem to work.

First of all, in all cases, I run the following: `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Then I have tried the following set of commands, from [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables):

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $public_if -o $private_if -p tcp --syn --dport $port -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $public_if -o $private_if -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $private_if -o $public_if -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $public_if -p tcp --dport $port -j DNAT --to-destination $guest_ip
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $private_if -p tcp --dport $port -d $guest_ip -j SNAT --to-source $private_ip
```

This does not do it. After `sudo iptables -F`, I also tried the following commands, from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/170079/forwarding-ports-to-guests-in-libvirt-kvm):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d $public_ip --dport $port -j DNAT --to-destination $guest_ip:$port
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -m state -d $private_ip/24 --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

And it did not work either. The port remains closed on `$public_ip`.

For more context, I am running these rules after I started my guest, and after starting the mock server on it.

What might I be doing wrong? Any suggestions on how I might debug this?

Update:

I tried running packet capture on both the host and the guest.

On the host:

`sudo tcpdump -i $private_if`

Absolutely no output on `nmap $public_ip -p $port`, but there is output when `nmap $guest_ip -p $port`.

On the guest:

`sudo tcpdump`

Exact same thing as above. Seems to indicate that the host is at fault.

Comment: Packet capture (tcpdump etc) is the usual debug tool – do the packets get forwarded to the host's virbr0? do they arrive at the guest's eth0? does the guest respond in any way?

Comment: It seems there is no forwarding happening. I have updated my question with my findings.

Comment: Oh God. I am such an idiot. I will write an answer soon expounding my idiocy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how it is tested.

Running `nmap $public_ip -p $port` on the host is not the same as running it on another machine on the network. Most importantly here, the SYN packet won't go through the PREROUTING hook, which directs the packet to the guest. It will only go through the OUTPUT and the POSTROUTING hooks, in that order.

For the record, the first set of lines does not work. The second set of lines does.